# Ext JS 4.1.1 - Summary Grid - How to Calc a Summary Column Using Other Values in Summary Row

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a summary grid that sums the values of two basic number columns but I want the next column in the summary row to show a calculation containing the values of the sums in the first two columns. Specifically, I want a Percent Change summary that reflects the change between the sums of the first two columns.

Here's a snippet of my grid with the three columns I'm talking about:

```
    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
    dataIndex: 'lastYearWages',
    text: 'LY Reg Wages',
    renderer: function(val, meta) {
        return '$' + Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000');
    },
    summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data) {
        return '$' + Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000');
    },
    summaryType: 'sum'      
}, {
    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
    dataIndex: 'thisYearWages',
    text: 'TY Reg Wages',
    renderer: function(val, meta) {
        return '$' + Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000');
    },
    summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data) {
        return '$' + Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000');
    },
    summaryType: 'sum'                
}, {
    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
    dataIndex: 'pctChg',
    text: '%Chg',
    renderer: function(val, meta) {
        meta.style = val < 0 ? "color: #FF0000;" : "color: #000000;";
        return Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000.00');
    },
    summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data) {
        ???
    },
    summaryType: ??   
    .
    .
    .
```

So really what I want is the third column to display the result of:
  (SumOfThisYearWages - SumOfLastYearWages) / SumOfLastYearWages

Can this be done? If so, how can I achieve it?

Thanks, in advance, for any feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got an answer on the Sencha forum...

The explanation was that the summary row contains access to the entire store so I can sum up the store anyway I want.

This did the trick:

```
summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data) {
    var lyRegWages = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#grid')[0].getStore().sum('lastYearWages');
    var tyRegWages = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#grid')[0].getStore().sum('thisYearWages');
    var percentage = (((tyRegWages-lyRegWages)/lyRegWages)*100).toFixed(2);
    return percentage.toString() + '%';
}
```